# magento2.4 not showing products

Tags: magento, magento2, bitnami, magento2.4

this my problem can check the page , https://www.elfanak.com/en_US/cravate.html
cant see the products
thanks for helping

sudo magento-cli cache:clean
sudo magento-cli  setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo magento-cli indexer:reindex

Answer (score 0):

just with the link to your page i can't figure out the problem go to var/log and see exception and system or go to developer mode to see the error.

Do this first
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush

find app/code var/view_preprocessed vendor pub/static app/etc generated/code generated/metadata ( -type f -or -type d ) -exec chmod u-w {} + && chmod o-rwx app/etc/env.php

chmod u+x bin/magento

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).